# handling __ scenarios with regex

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have the data like

```
BR_TheDailyBeast.com__ROS_BN_DT_ROS Leaderboard_SUB_728x90
BR_CNET_ROS_BN_DT_Cnet reviewsAddedValueMid-pageMPU_SUB_300x250
```

O/P # BN and BN

Actual O/P # ROS and BN

i need to extract between 3rd and 4th underscore. when i used '`[^_]+',1,4` it is extracting properly but where ever the data like `__` then it is treating single underscore.

how should i handle those cases as well in parsing logic.

please suggest me on this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
regexp_substr(your_string, '_([^_]*)', 1, 3, null, 1)
```

You could also simply use the normal substr and instr functions.

```
substr(your_string, 
       instr(your_string,'_',1,3) + 1,
       instr(your_string,'_',1,4) - instr(your_string,'_',1,3) - 1
      )
```

Comment: ya i can use substr and instr, but regexp will looks simple code. that to i am using regexp_extract.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. Isn't [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/101) what you want?

Comment: with this '_([^_]*)', 1, 3 i am getting exact output but with _. the getting output is like _ROS and _BN. so i dont need _

Comment: @Dileep You have to add two more parameters: `NULL` and `1`, just as in Ramblin' Man's example.

Comment: regexp_substr has 6th parameter `subexpr` which extracts only the part of the regex. That's the reason i have wrapped [^_]* in brackets and used 1 as subexpr.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej i am not using regexp_substr, i am using regexp_extract it is in IBM Netezza.

Comment: @Dileep Then just enclose your `regexp_extract` in this: `LTRIM(regexp_extract(...), '_')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
SELECT
  regexp_substr('BR_TheDailyBeast.com__ROS_BN_DT_ROS Leaderboard_SUB_728x90', '_+([^_]*)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) AS val1,
  regexp_substr('BR_CNET_ROS_BN_DT_Cnet reviewsAddedValueMid-pageMPU_SUB_300x250', '_+([^_]*)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) AS val2
FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
VAL1 VAL2
---- ----
BN   BN
```